# Console hex editor under Cygwin?

Tags: windows, linux, cygwin, hex-editor

Could recommend for a console hex editor under [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a package called [hexedit](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=hexedit) that comes up in Cygwin's package search, which I assume is a port of the same tool that is available in most Linux distributions under the same name.

I've used said utility (as installed from the Debian repositories) under Linux, and it did the job I was wanting it to do. I've not tried the version in Cygwin though so it could be a different tool with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Both [vi](http://www.kpsolution.com/blog/tips/how-to-edit-hex-file-in-vi/5/) and [Emacs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_464.html) can do that and both are available under Cygwin.

Note that both Emacs and vi can be run in a console or in windowed mode.

Comment: vim++ .. has native win32 binaries (not only cygwin). vim does hex editing via a helper tool called "xxd".

Comment: in emacs use the hexl-find-file to work with hexl editor  (wee

Comment: Thanks, but `vi` is miserable for editing binary if  you have to insert or delete bytes!  Sadly, xxd does not seem to have a way to omit the offset, other than using the PDF (completely unformatted) style.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `bvi`. Its [home page](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/) is on sourceforge and there is a Cygwin package for it. As the name implies, its UI is very much like `vi`.